# HUGE query execution time difference between oracle 10g and 9i

Tags: oracle, query-optimization, data-dictionary

I'm running the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM all_tab_cols c
LEFT JOIN all_varrays v ON c.owner = v.owner
    AND c.table_name = v.parent_table_name
    AND c.column_name = v.parent_table_column
```

On a 10g server this takes ~2s, on 9i this takes 819s (13 mins)! What on earth is causing this huge performance difference, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Why does it matter? Why not just use Oracle 10/11g?

Comment: Because the app I'm developing needs to connect to 11g, 10g and 9i.

Comment: First question:  are the rowcounts from all_tab_cols and all_varrays the same between the two databases you are comparing?

Comment: same order of magnitude. 9i: 35046, 301. 10g: 50317, 383. So the 9i server should be doing much less work.

Comment: Can you look at the query plan?

Comment: Taking a stab here, since I'm not sure what the logical intent of your query is, but could it be that what you really want is (and I know the lack of comment formatting will mangle this): SELECT * 
FROM all_tab_cols c  
     ,all_varrays v 
where
c.owner = v.owner
    AND c.table_name = v.parent_table_name
    AND c.column_name = v.parent_table_column
/*i.e. no outer join?*/

Comment: I want the information on all table columns, but with extra information on varrays if the column does have a varray datatype (this is actually significantly simplified; there are further left joins as well, but this is the simple case that is just as slow)

Comment: On my Oracle 9i database even "SELECT * FROM ALL_TAB_COLS" takes a long time (a minute).  Does yours?

Comment: @Janek - I'm trying to run EXPLAIN PLAN, but it keeps on complaining I have insufficient privileges, even though I've granted SELECT ALL DICTIONARY to the user, and have a public synonym for sys.plan_table, with full public grants...

Comment: @Tony: selecting from all_tab_cols only takes a couple of the seconds, its the join that kills it

Comment: Right, I've got the query plan, but when I try to specify a query hint `USE_HASH(v)` I get an ORA-1760 illegal argument for function. Where on earth is this coming from?

Comment: Adding the `USE_HASH(v)` hint here drops execution to between 2 and 4s, for 29785/3 rows on the views and returning 30112 results. I gave up on the non-hint version after 5 minutes. Not sure how a hint can cause that error, how are you formatting it?

Comment: select /*+USE_HASH(v) */ * from all_tab_cols c 
left join all_varrays v on c.owner = v.owner
and c.table_name = v.parent_table_name
and c.column_name = v.parent_table_column

Comment: So the normal way then. Sorry, I'm out, no idea how that could generate the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that, by default, 9i doesn't have statistics on the system tables, whereas 10g+ does. This is what's causing the performance difference - Oracle doesn't know how it should be joining it correctly.

Answer (score 3):

One potential explanation for the disparity is data dictionary stats.  In 10g Oracle introduced the [DBMS_STATS.GATHER_DICTIONARY_STATS() procedure](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_stats.htm#i1055451), which gathers stats against the SYS and SYSTEM schemas (and some others).  Having statistics on the data dictionary could result in an improved execution plan for some queries against database views.

Even if you run DBMS_STATS.GATHER_DATABASE_STATS() it still gathers stats for the data dictionary, unless you explicitly set the `gather_sys` parameter to `false`.

You can check what statistics gather operations have been run against the 10g database with this query:

```
SQL> select * from  DBA_OPTSTAT_OPERATIONS
  2  order by start_time asc
  3  /

OPERATION                                                        TARGET
---------------------------------------------------------------- ----------------
START_TIME
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
END_TIME
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
gather_database_stats(auto)
10-APR-10 06.00.03.953000 +01:00
10-APR-10 06.18.21.281000 +01:00

<snip/>

gather_database_stats(auto)
03-MAY-10 22.00.05.734000 +01:00
03-MAY-10 22.03.08.328000 +01:00

gather_dictionary_stats
06-MAY-10 13.48.49.839000 +01:00
06-MAY-10 13.57.42.252000 +01:00


10 rows selected.

SQL>
```